# php local connection mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ios, phpmyadmin

I try to make a simple IOS app that can connect to mysql database and read one table. But my php code does't work and really have no idea why, it's seems correct to me. The database is in a raspberry phpmyadmin server and the server works great. 
I will put my code here and please tell me what's wrong.

```
<?php

$host = "192.168.2.193";
$db = "produtos";
$user = "root";
$pass = "1234";

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if(!$connection)
{
die("Database server connection failed.");
}
else
{
//attempt to select the database
$dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

//check to see if we could select the database
if(!dbconnect)
{
       die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
    $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

    $records = array();

    //loop throught all our records and add them to our array

    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
    {
        $records[] = $r;
    }

    echo json_ecode($records);
    echo $resultset; 

}
}

?>
```

Comment: 1) You're using the obsolete/deprecated mysql_*() functions. 2) `if (!dbconnect)` - missing a $, perhaps? 3) Assuming your query call can never fail and not bothering to check for error conditions. 4) outputting json on every iteration of your loop, which will produce bad json 5) echoing out your result handle, so you're mixing bad data in with your bad json. 6) shall we continue...? 7) yes, let's continue: using the `root` account in a web-facing script. bad idea

Comment: Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: use `mysqli_connect` rather than `mysql_connect` because `mysql_connect` is deprecated and will not work someday. Also what is the the error you are getting? change your die() statement to something more helpful `die(mysqli_error($connection));`

Comment: Hi, and thank you for help. I change all functions to mysqli and add the error reporting and the report give me this: 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.2.193' (111) in /var/www/server.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/server.php on line 25

Comment: That error would suggest that you either A) don't have the right IP address or B) there is a network issue between your host server and the SQL server, is this code running on the same server that is hosting the SQL database? if so then you can probably just use localhost for your `$host` var.

Comment: thank you, error solved :D:D. I put localhost and work. Now I have other error, but this one I think I can solve. Tank you so much!

Comment: I formulated an answer for you if you want to accept it, Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I can't really solve this error it's giving this "Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /var/www/server.php on line 30
Unable to connect to the specified database!" could you help me again? thank you!

Comment: switch your parameters `$dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);` to `$dbconnect = mysql_select_db($connection, $db);` The error is telling you parameter 1 must be mysqli but you are passing the database name in as parameter 1.

Comment: thank you. but now tells me that Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string, but I need that result in a string. How can I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question:

use `mysqli_connect` rather than `mysql_connect` because `mysql_connect` is deprecated and will not work someday. Also what is the the error you are getting? change your `die()` statement to something more helpful `die(mysqli_error($connection));`

Based on your comment:

That error would suggest that you either A) don't have the right IP address or B) there is a network issue between your host server and the SQL server, is this code running on the same server that is hosting the SQL database? if so then you can probably just use localhost for your $host